# Wicket 7 - Wizard finish button generates multiple onClick events

Tags: java, wicket

We're using the Wicket `Wizard` component. On the last step of the wizard, we find that if the user clicks the finish button rapidly, then Wicket calls our `onFinish()` method multiple times. This causes problems for us.
Interestingly, the problem occurs in all browsers we've tried (IE, Chrome), but not in Firefox. This browser appears to detect the multiple clicks, and only sends one click event to the server.

Question is, what can we do to prevent this? 
From looking at the Wicket framework code, I can see that the nav buttons are contained in a `WizardButtonBar`, and the `FinishButton` is handling the `onClick` event, but I'm unsure of the correct way to override or control this behaviour, and somehow detect the multiple `onClick` events

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to use Ajax, do you?

If you did, you could just add a veil - e.g. by overriding `#getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId()` - and any double submit would be prevented. Additional benefit: If the user pressed the back button after the wizard has finished, the browser will leave the wizard and the user cannot finish it a second time.

For non-Ajax request, you'll have to add your own veil JavaScript to your button.
To prevent the user from going back and finishing the wizard a second time, you can use a token-base solution:
On start of the wizard aquire a token (could just be a counter). Once the wizard has finished, mark the token as expended (e.g. store it along your domain objects).
On each request to the wizard, you can check whether the token is still valid - if not, redirect the user to another page explaning that the wizard has already finished.

Comment: Thanks Sven. Just using the standard Wicket Wizard component. If you guys could provide an Ajax enabled Wizard that would be great ;)

Comment: It's already there: override newButtonBar() and let it return an `AjaxWizardButtonBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew very kindly submitted the original question for me. I did try doing this (pretty much as you suggested):

```
class MyWizard extends Wizard {

    private Integer finishPressed = -1; // deliberately set an invalid value to start with

    public MyWizard() {
        finishPressed = 0;  // only place where finishedPressed is set to 0
        log.info( "init: finishPressed={}", finishPressed );
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        log.info( "begin: finishPressed={}", finishPressed );
        if ( ! finishPressed ) {
            finishPressed += 1;
            // do onFinish actions ...
        }
        log.info( "end: finishPressed={}", finishPressed );
    }
}
```

However, what I find is that onFinish() is called as many times as I pressed the Finish button, *but each time finishPressed is 0 when it enters the method*, instead of the count incrementing.

Note: I only ever see "init: finishPressed=0" *once* in the log. I don't know how it keeps getting reset to 0. However, I did notice that the onFinish() calls were handled by a different thread each time. But as said, the constructor (the only place finishPressed is set to 0) was only called once.

Only by declaring finishPressed as static (which obviously will cause problems in real live operation) do I see the finishPressed incrementing as expected.